# Displaying portions of multiple pages from a given category, in a single summary page

Tags: categories

I'm a novice at WordPress, although I have been using Movable Type for years.
And I'm confident that this is a simple issue that I just don't know the right jargon to search for properly. Sorry.

I have a site displaying all the pages in a selected category. The problem is that it displays ALL of every page, and that's too long. I would like to set up the individual pages with a shorter introduction section at the top, and more content following. When and individual page is selected directly it shows the intro section and the other content as a single integrated page.
When the summary page is selected, it shows all pages in that category, but only the introduction section from each page. Since this introduction section is maybe only a paragraph or so long, I get a summary page that makes it easy to see the lead-ins without all the details.

The current results page for category=publication
http://www.celaenopress.com/wp/category/publication/

What I really want it to look like:
http://www.celaenopress.com/wp/

If there's a tutorial or other information on how to do this please give me the URL and I'll go study it myself!

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This is something that depends on the theme. Are you developing a theme or using one off-the-shelf? If you're developing one yourself it's as simple as using `the_excerpt()` in the template instead of `the_content()`. If you're using an existing theme you'll need to check with the author to see if it's a change you can make.

Comment: Yes, I am using a theme. Thank you.
I'll have a look and see!